# Is it possible to align a menu to the right of the menu bar using wxPython?

Tags: python, menu, cross-platform, wxpython, menubar

I'm trying to create a menu bar in wxPython 2.8.11.0 and Python 2.7 where most of the menus are left aligned (as normal) but one is - ideally - right aligned, or at least separated in some way from the rest.

Is this possible?

EDIT: This needs to be a cross-platform solution.

Comment: I don't think that's possible in wx, at least not with MenuBar.  The first ugly workaround that came to mind was inserting an empty menu as a divider with nothing but spaces for a title.  Almost as ugly would be creating a fake separator by giving the second to last menu a title like `"&Edit      | "`.

Answer (score 1):

If the native menubar doesn't support it, then wxPython probably won't either. There is a pure Python implementation of the menubar though. It's called FlatMenu. I would try that. If it doesn't work, at least you can hack it or submit a patch in Python code rather than trying to figure out the C++ for fixing wxWidgets.